# m2e Embedded Runtime: Global Settings File read from wrong location

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

In Eclipse, I have configured a global settings file under `Preferences > Maven > User Settings > Global Settings`. This file contains a mirror configuration for repositories.

When Eclipse attempts to download dependencies, the settings in this file are used. When starting a maven build via `Run As > Maven build`, dependency resolution errors occur. When starting a Maven runtime outside from Eclipse, everything works as expected.

I enabled debug output and found the following line when starting a Maven build inside eclipse.

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED\conf\settings.xml
```

**Why is the configured global config file not used when starting a build in Eclipse?** What confuses me especially is Eclipse does use these settings when downloading dependencies in the workspace.

Interestingly, a configured user settings file *is* used when starting a build from within Eclipse.