# Where are the global settings for eclipse m2e?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

I'm using m2e in eclipse v2020-12. I created a settings.xml file in `D:\.m2repo` with `<localRepository>D:/.m2repo/repository</localRepository>`. In eclipse preferences, under Maven, Global Settings, I browsed to that file then clicked `Update Settings`. After closing eclipse, I moved m2e's repo from the default folder `C:\Users\<user>\.m2` to `D:\` (it's 30GB and I needed space on C).

Some parts of eclipse recognize the change. Maven user settings shows the new local repo folder and Java classpath variables under build path settings shows `MT_REPO (non modifiable) - D:\.m2repo\repository.`

However, m2e is still (stubbornly) creating some files in the default folder on C. The most relevant info I could find was a hint of another global settings file in the error message of [this 2017 unanswered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944192/m2e-embedded-runtime-global-settings-file-read-from-wrong-location):

> [DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED\conf\settings.xml

**EDIT:**
[Found maven doc here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) saying that user settings are "dominant" over global settings. So, I tried the above with the same settings file under Maven, User Settings... same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said: unanswered!

I got it under control (empty/no writes to `~/.m2/repository`) after:

1. *Using (in m2e) a "standalone" maven* installation. (It's global config location *is definitely* `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`) [[1]](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)*
2. (Leaving global config untouched,) Having consistent `~/.m2/settings.xml` pointing to `<localRepository>D:/...</localRepository>`.
3. "Restoring Defaults" or providing consistent m2e "user (& global) settings".
4. And to be safe: Re-start your workspace! and even safer: the jvm! ;)

*: m2e's embedded maven has more bugs & limitations... (to prove)

Comment: By "standalone", you mean install maven right?

Comment: Correct! And select it in "m2e installations settings". ;)

Comment: Seems that m2e is similar to egit in that the eclipse implementation of these tools is incomplete. I had to install Git for Windows to fill in the gaps and will do the same for maven. Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted because but didn't accept as answer. While this might eliminate m2e's use of drive C, it doesn't really answer the question.